# git archive returns with "fatal: Not a valid object"

Tags: git

Trying to create an archive for deployment, but I'm getting an error. No idea why -- I've done other deployments using this same line.

```
git archive --format=zip --output=filename.zip HEAD:www
```

Comment: Is `www` a top-level directory in the current `HEAD` revision of the repo?  (To clarify: I'm suspecting that when you ran this before, such a directory existed. But this time, is it a different repo with different structure; or was the directory removed or renamed?  If so `HEAD:www` would no longer be a valid tree-ish.)

Comment: That was it. My other scripts used separate repos for client/server/app stuff, but I put this new one in a single repo. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just in case anyone else stumbles across this while googling, for me the problem was a bad parameter to git archive and it was trying to interpret the bad parameter as the "tree-ish".

I forgot the -- in front of my output=blah.zip so it was trying to find the tree "output=blah.zip".

Answer (score 1):

Well in my case it is a missing parameter, it interprets the first name ofter output as the ref to base the archive on.

wrong:

```
git archive -o /c/work/220402_PX_Integrate_P4TA.zip $(git diff --name-only 220402_Testmerge_prep_P4TA..PX_Integrate_P4TA)
```

gives you the error:

> fatal: not a valid object name: codeunit/codeunit_0000000002.txt

which is the first return value from git diff, but not a ref, it's a file.

working:

```
git archive -o /c/work/220402_PX_Integrate_P4TA.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only 220402_Testmerge_prep_P4TA..PX_Integrate_P4TA)
```

The first parameter is now HEAD, the current tip of the repository. Still should be the version you want to export, though.